# WS_EX_LAYERED with SetParent() doesn't show the window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have this one problem I just can't solve. I'm trying to make a window from my application that is transparent (using flags `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED`) a child to another window, which is not transparent.

When I don't use the call `SetParent( my_window, target_parent_window )` with my_window having the `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag, the new child window won't be visible.

I found out that a manifest entry could help me, since having a child window with flag `WS_EX_LAYERED` is supported since Windows 8. I tried it without any success.

```
::SetWindowLongW( process_window, GWL_STYLE, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE );
::SetWindowLongW( process_window, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW );

::SetWindowPos( process_window, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );
::ShowWindow( process_window, SW_SHOW );

::SetParent( process_window, new_parent_window); // if i skip this call the window will render perfectly
```

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent): _"For compatibility reasons, SetParent does not modify the WS_CHILD or WS_POPUP window styles of the window whose parent is being changed."_

Comment: Is the parent window in the same process as the child window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features

> To create a layered window, specify the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style when calling the `CreateWindowEx` function, or call the `SetWindowLong` function to set `WS_EX_LAYERED` after the window has been created. After the `CreateWindowEx` call, the layered window will not become visible until the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` or `UpdateLayeredWindow` function has been called for this window.